# Cannot display angularJS scope components

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, laravel

I am making a web application using AngularJS and Laravel. The application is meant to allow the user to post a note on a board. With the code I have, when submitting the note it gets saved to the database but it does not display on the page.

angulartest.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<title>Test angular</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="NoteController">
<h3>Add note</h3>
<form  ng-submit="addNote()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newNote.content">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="note in notes">
        @{{ note.content }}
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.factory('Data', function Data($http) {
 return {
    getNotes: function getNotes() { return $http.get('/notes/all'); },
    addNote: function addNote(data) { return $http.post('/notes', data); },
    removeNote: function removeNote(id) { return $http.delete('/notes?id='+ id); } 
 } 
});


app.controller('NoteController', function NoteController($scope, Data) {
Data.getNotes().success(parseNotes);

function parseNotes(data) {
    $scope.notes = data;
}

$scope.newNote = { content: '', poster: '' };

$scope.addNote = function addNote() {
    Data.addNote({
        content: $scope.newNote.content,
        poster: $scope.newNote.post
    })
    .success(noteAddSuccess).error(noteAddError);
}

function noteAddSuccess(data) {
    $scope.error = null;
    $scope.notes.push(data);
    console.log($scope.notes);
    $scope.newNote = { content: '', poster: '' };
}

function noteAddError(data) {
    $scope.error = data;
}

$scope.removeNote = function removeNote(id) {
    if (confirm('Do you really want to remove this note?')) {
        Data.removeNote(id).success(noteRemoveSuccess);
    }
}

function noteRemoveSuccess(data) {
    var i = $scope.notes.length;
    while (i--) {
        if ($scope.notes[i].id == data) {
            $scope.notes.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
});
```

I believe this is all the relevant code. I'm not sure why it is not displaying note.content 
Thank you

Comment: could you provide your code on fiddle?

Comment: does the ajax request in `Data.addNote` return the full note object? There's not much troubleshooting information here

Answer (score 0):

Since the data update is not triggered from UI, i.e on user clicks or similar activity the scope might be unaware of the changes. In your code you are updating the data from the service, thus my first suggestion will be is to use $scope.$apply() to propagate the changes on the model to the UI.

```
function parseNotes(data) {
  $scope.notes = data;
  if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
  }
}
```

This might help. If not then, please post back

Comment: It is triggered by the submit button in the form

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, really simple. I was closing div tag before I was requesting {{note.content}}. It should look like:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="NoteController">
<h3>Add note</h3>
<form  ng-submit="addNote()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newNote.content">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="note in notes">
        @{{ note.content }}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

thank you for the replies!